# Is it possible to access XC16/gcc target flags from within code?

Tags: gcc, pic, xc16

I am compiling code for Microchip dspic33 series processors using Microchip's XC16 compiler.

I have some code that is used in several applications (i.e. it is in a code library). For certain modules, I want to ensure that certain compiler flags are set during compilation, ideally using the pre-processor. In particular, I am interested in testing for the -mauxflash and -code-in-auxflash target flags.

Is there a way to test for compiler options during compilation?

I have tried dumping all the #defines using xc16-gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null, but nothing seems to change. There are 3 defines related to auxflash (**AUXFLASH_LENGTH, __AUXFLASH_BASE, and __HAS_AUXFLASH**), but nothing related to the target flags.

Answer (score 2):

not all flags affect CPP defines, so you might be SOL there.  your use of `-dM -E` is the best way to check.

however, there are a few features that might be useful to you:

1. [`-grecord-gcc-switches`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html): this records all the flags used at compile time on a per-object basis in the DWARF info.  you could then have a script that checks the objects and throws an error if one was built w/out the flag you care about.
2. [`__attribute__((optimize("flags")))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html): gcc lets you force specific flags on a per-function basis.
3. [`#pragma GCC optimize ("flags")`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html): gcc lets you force specific flags at the file level.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the flags get interpreted as -f options instead of -m options, so they are not recognized. I poked around a bit and discovered `#pragma GCC target("flags")`, but using this in XC16 flavoured GCC results in the error `#pragma GCC target is not supported for this machine`. I guess the options you suggested are good for changing optimization levels, etc., but not -m options.

Comment: Further to the above, I just realized that the -m options I happen to be concerned with (`auxflash` and `const-in-auxflash`) are memory model options, and not target options. Perhaps there is no way to set these using pragmas.